# check if HGetAll is found

Tags: go, redis

Is it possible to check straight away if the key was found before doing more processing on the result?

```
res := client.HGetAll(ctx, key)
err := res.Err()
if err != nil {
    panic("Redis hgetall: "+err.Error())
}
```

When fetching a key you can do `err == redis.Nil`

```
value, err := client.Get(ctx, key).Result()
empty := err == redis.Nil
if err != nil && !empty {
    panic("Redis get: "+err.Error())
}
return value, !empty
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the key does not exist:

For the GET command, redis-server does return a `(nil)` response hence you can check for the `redis.Nil` error.

For the HGETALL command, redis-server will return something along the lines of `(empty list or set)` which is not the same as nil hence why the library authors (go-redis) may have decided that it is not worthy of returning a redis.Nil error (or any similar error).

Your best bet would be to check if the returned "list or set" (`res.Val()`) is empty.

Comment: compile error `res.Value undefined (type *redis.MapStringStringCmd has no field or method Value)`

Comment: My bad, it should be `Val()`

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Here is an example of how to find the state of the operation:

```golang
val, err := rdb.Get(ctx, "key").Result()
switch {
case err == redis.Nil:
    fmt.Println("key does not exist")
case err != nil:
    fmt.Println("Get failed", err)
case val == "":
    fmt.Println("value is empty")
}
```

[Read more in `go-redis` docs](https://redis.uptrace.dev/guide/go-redis.html#redis-nil)

You can also use `Exists` to check if a key exists.